# Destroying login page window and opening a new one

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to close a window while creating a new one. The following function runs once a login has been entered. Do you have any suggestions on how to close this window while the MenuPage(window) is opened?

```
from tkinter import *

class LoginPage():
 def __init__(self):
  window = Tk()

  #UI to retrieve login details
  #While loop when submit is clicked.

  if UserLogins:

    #Maybe here a close window function is ran

    window = Toplevel()
    start= MenuPage(window)

  else:
    print('Incorrect Login')

class MenuPage(object):

 #Menu UI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginPage()
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please replace the code above with [mcve] for getting a proper answer. How exactly are the SQL parts relevant for example?

Comment: Apologies, I hope you spot the solution now

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**.

Your main issue is your class `LoginPage`.
You do initialize `Tk()` inside the `__init__` of your class. As soon as this object is destroyed, the Tkinter Instance gets destroyed as well.

Consider using the following approach:

1. Create a Main Widget (e.g. based on `Toplevel` or `Tk`)
2. Create a LoginPage based on e.g. `Frame` inside your Main Widget
3. After login attempt, either destroy the `LoginPage` and create another `Frame` holding new data. (MenuPage)

Using this approach your Tkinter Main Instance Runs all the time, and you delete or add objects / widgets to it.

If you do not use your `MainWidget` (that should persist) as Tk-Instance, an "unnamed" Instance will be used for that. Alternatively use `Tk()` as Parent for your LoginPage, but do not embed it inside it.

Pseudo Code Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWidget(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__()
        self.__load_widgets()
    def __load_widgets(self):
        self.page = LoginPage(self)
        self.page.bind("<LoginEvent>", self.show_menu)
        self.page.grid(sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)
    def show_menu(self, event=None):
        self.page.destroy()
        self.page=MenuPage(self)
        self.page.grid(sticky=tk.NW+tk.SE)

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def raise_login_result(self):
        """ some event may raise the event you can use from main widget to bind to """
        # ...
        raise("<LoginEvent>")

class MenuPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWidget()
    app.mainloop()
```

**Edit**
As your question expands into geometry managers, I hereby refer to one corresponding [documentation on geometry managers](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm)(that is e.g. grid/pack/place). This documentation shows the corresponding interfaces.

Comment: Due to issues with using global variables, frames have caused issues earlier in the coding of my program. Is there a way to hide a window maybe?

Comment: using e.g. `grid_remove()` ?

Comment: In terms actually removing the window so that only the menu appears once logged in. I have used the place method for the positioning of widgets if that helps